# I have a project in SwiftUI, I want to implement the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-storyboard

I'm new in Xcode and iOS development and I have a project which is working on SwiftUI by default and I need to implement new screens using my Main.storyboard

I tried to put in
SceneDelegate.swift

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeController") as! HomeController
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()}
```

It doesn't work, unfortunately.

AppDelegate.swift

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
     
    return true
}
```

Thank you

Comment: How doesn't it work? Is the app crashing? Displaying a blank screen? Failing to compile?...

Comment: No crashing, Only showing to me the SwiftUI main scene. I want to run by default as a storyboard.